# I'm trying to move one element from a <select> list to the top, but my code doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this page](https://breatheology.safechkout.net/black_friday), and there is a <select> drop-down list next to
"Billing State (non-US scroll to bottom)"

I want to use Javascript to put the last item of that list (My state is not listed) to the top of the list.

So far I tried this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("select[name=billing_state]").find('option[value="_NOTLISTED_"]').prependTo($("select[name=billing_state]"));
});
</script>
```

I don't know why, it works on http://jsfiddle.net/4kHuA/21/, but it doesn't work when I modify the html page and test it on the browser.

I'm not very experienced with Javascript, so maybe I did something really dumb.

Comment: i hope the issue is when your line of code runs the element is not rendered , can you try `console.log($("select[name=billing_state]"));`

Comment: Where did you place this script on your web page? I didn't find it.

Comment: I didn't, I'm testing it locally. I can't change the page right now. I don't even know if I did it right to be honest. I downloaded the page, added the script after the </title> tag, saved, and opened the page on Firefox.

Comment: You have to make sure jquery.js which you refer to as $ has loaded before you call it in your script.

Comment: Try pasting it right before `</body>` instead.

Comment: Ok, I pasted it right before </body>, now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure jquery.js which you refer to as $ has loaded before you call it in your script. As @Sergio wrote, placing it before `</body>` tag may help a lot.